# Initialize many strings and each string with many values to a variable. Perform operations on strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

This is my second question in stackoverflow and I am a beginner to Python. I don't know how to post a question here. Forgive me for any mistake. Please, help me. Thank you for your valuable time and response.

I have explained here my requirement through following simple problem. Consider the following case:

```
G = range(100,1000,100) #= [100, ..,1000]=total values (n) = 10 
I = range(0,2,0.1) #= [0 0.1 ........2]=total values(m) = 20
V = f(G,I)
```

For each value of G, V is computed for all values of I as given below:

```
    for i in G:
        for j in I:
            V = f(i,j)
```

The variable V should store 'n' strings and each string with 'm' values. Finally, V may look something like this V = {[1,2,3,...(m values)],[4,6,....,(m values)],....,[10,20,...(m values)]}

**Q1:** How to initialize V to store n strings, each string consisting m values? Note that, m and n values may change for case to case

**Q2:** how to store the values in V which are calculated from formula in for loop

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: five questions in one question?

Comment: I have programmed to calculate V for a particular value of G and all values of I. I got one string output for V and even plotted the result. This is fine. I don't know how to calculate V for 'n' values of G and 'm' values of I. Please, help me.

Comment: Sorry that I have put five questions. I am new to this community. Joined just  1 hour before. I am learning how to post questions. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1,A2: It looks like you want V to be a list of lists, where the outer list has n lists of m values, where each value is f(i,j). For this, you don't need to pre-initialize the list, you can just use the append method. While iterating, the enumerate method will give you the index of the current element in G, so you can access the current list in V.

The following will build your list of lists:

```
V = []
for outerListIndex, i in enumerate(G):
    V.append([])
    for j in I:
        V[outerListIndex].append(f(i,j))
```

Comment: Excellent. It worked. Now, I want to plot V (n strings, each string of m values) and I(m values) in matplotlib. Could you please, tell me the code for it.